# Instantiating WSGIApplication in webapp2

Tags: python, webapp2

In webapp2, I can instantiate an app like this...

```
routes = [('/products', 'ProductsHandler'),
          ('/', 'HomeHandler')]

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes=routes)
```

None of the parameters are required.  So, I figure I can instantiate like this...

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication()
app.routes = [('/products', 'ProductsHandler'),
              ('/', 'HomeHandler')]
```

However, the routes don't seem to be working this way.  I'm getting 404 on both pages.

Is there something wrong with my syntax or is there something about WSGI that I don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webapp2 does some magic on routes (converting from the tuples to `webapp2.Route` instances). When you just assign to routes, it won't work because they haven't been converted to the right format for webapp2. I believe you can just add in the Route instantiation and it should work.

Comment: Got it.  I'm sticking with the recommended approach.